# Google Guava - pass parameters to load method in addition go KEY

Tags: java, caching, parameters, parameter-passing, guava

I have written a program to cache objects using Google Guava. My problem is how to pass additional parameters to Guava Load method. Here is the code. Below you see in this line - I have made fileId and pageno as key - cache.get(fileID+pageNo);. Now when cache.get is called and when that key is not in the cache - guava will call the load method of class PreviewCacheLoader which I have given below as well.

```
public class PreviewCache {
    static final LoadingCache<String, CoreObject> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
          .maximumSize(1000)
          .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) 
          .build(new PreviewCacheLoader());

   public CoreObject getPreview(String strTempPath, int pageNo, int requiredHeight, String fileID, String strFileExt,  String ssoId) throws IOException 
    {
        CoreObject coreObject = null;
        try {
            coreObject = cache.get(fileID+pageNo, HOW TO PASS pageNO and requiredHeight because I want to keep key as ONLY fileID+pageNo );
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return coreObject;
    }
}
```

How to pass parameters from above  which are int and String to below Load method in addition to key parameter

```
public class PreviewCacheLoader extends CacheLoader<String, CoreObject> {

@Override
public CoreObject load(String fileIDpageNo, HOW TO GET pageNO and requiredHeight) throws Exception {

    CoreObject coreObject = new CoreObject();
    // MAKE USE OF PARAMETERS pageNO and requiredHeight
    // Populate coreObject here 
    return coreObject;


}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

For starters, it's extremely bad programming practice to use `fileId + pageNo` as a `String` key instead of creating a proper object.  (This is called "stringly typed" code.)  The best way to solve your problem would probably look like:

```
class FileIdAndPageNo {
  private final String fileId;
  private final int pageNo;
  ...constructor, hashCode, equals...
}
public CoreObject getPreview(final int pageNo, final int requiredHeight, String fileID) { throws IOException 
{
    CoreObject coreObject = null;
    try {
        coreObject = cache.get(new FileIdAndPageNo(fileID, pageNo),
           new Callable<CoreObject>() {
             public CoreObject call() throws Exception {
               // you have access to pageNo and requiredHeight here
             }
           });
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return coreObject;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Louis - So in that case do I need these two things. 1.  .build(new PreviewCacheLoader()); 2. And entire PreviewCacheLoader class. What I understood is I need to move the logic of load method in  PreviewCacheLoader class to the callable call method. Is that correct ?

Comment: No, you don't need to have a `CacheLoader` anymore after this point, you can just do `.build()`; yes, you would move all the logic into the `Callable`.

Comment: Good answer.  I would just add that the hashCode() and equals() implementation are **Required** on the FieldIdAndPageNo class, otherwise the Cache won't ever treat 2 keys as being the same.